# How do you grab data from a text file, then use the extracted data in the Python file?

Tags: python, selenium, text-files

I have a text file with my email and password address,

Text file:

email: email@address.com

password: password123

I'd like to extract the data from the text file, using the variables "email" and input it into my code, using Selenium.

For example:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_name("emailAddress")
search.send_keys(EmailFromTextFile)
```

How?

Comment: Actually your text file doesn't know it contains any variables. They are just text. Plus selenium is only web based (AGAIK) and can not look into text files. So I'm confused regarding your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open("file/location.txt","r") as f:
    txt = f.read()
email = txt.split("password")[0].split(":")[1].strip()
password = txt.split(":")[2].strip()
```

Comment: hi there, i have updated my post.. could you please help me again haha

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
myfile = open("text.txt","r")  # text.txt is the file name, r means read file.
contents = myfile.read()
print(contents)
myfile.close()
```

You can get more information about Python file handling in *[Python File Open](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_handling.asp)*.

Comment: hey, i  updated my question to be more specific, sorry about that

Comment: Ohhh, it's all good. There are some of the answers you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way using a regular expression:

```
import re

# There would be other code here to set up Selenium and
# define the variable `driver`

with open('/tmp/data.txt') as f:
    buf = f.read()

expr = re.compile(r"email:\s*([^\s]+)\s+password: (.*)")

m = expr.match(buf)
if m:
    email = m.group(1)
    password = m.group(2)
    search = driver.find_element_by_name("emailAddress") 
    search.send_keys(email)
```

Comment: hi there, i have updated my post to use selenium.. any way to do this?

Comment: I changed my answer a bit.  Is that what you're asking for?

Comment: hi there, yep it is thank you so much steve! appreciate it so much